# Synchronizing Evolution Email Inboxes Across Multiple Computers

Tags: email, synchronization, evolution

I'd like to synchronize evolution inbox across 2-3 computers without leaving messages on the server.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  I can't seem to find any way to do this by searching server fault or Google.

What I've thought about doing is using rsync to make diffs every time I check my mail and transfer them to a service like drop box or ubuntu one.  Then I can download the diffs when I use another machine.

I think it would take a decent amount of work to get this going, so if there's an easier way I'd appreciate knowing about it.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use IMAP. It leaves all your mail on the server and allows you to connect to it from anywhere.

Comment: I'm aware of IMAP and how it works.  I don't want to leave messages n the server.

Comment: Edited that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to synchronize between multiple clients, I assume you have network connection. So, the reason of not wanting IMAP has to be you don't trust the provider. Then, you can either: use a different provider or if you don't trust any, you could install your own IMAP server (like dovecot).

If you have other reasons not to use IMAP please explain.

Comment: I don't think this helps. There are many use cases in which those are invalid. eg private network with intermitent connection to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other ways to do it? I am in the same position and I don't want to use IMAP. The reason is not that I don't trust the provider. My scenario is as follows. I have a laptop that receives emails with evolution from different email accounts.

Now I also want to use a netbook to work with once in a while and I would like to use it and have my emails available there too. With Internet connection even check my emails with it. So later I would like to synchronize from the netbook the latest my emails to the laptop.

There seems to be Ubuntu One having a feature to synchronize mails, but I haven't figured out how to set it up. I can sync files with it, but not emails.

Any other ways to do it? Just copy the email folder over?